# Not able to Resize an Event in React-Big-Calender

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

i am using **React-Big-Calender**, i want to make my event resizable. I am able to implement dnd of events but somehow events are not resizing. I took reference from official example (https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/examples/demos/dnd.js) but still not able to make it work. Please help..!
Link to my codeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-darwin-35hq4?file=/src/CalenderIndex.jsx

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this and it ended up being due to my react and react-dom version being 17.0.1. It looks like they changed how some DOM events are handled (https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html) which causes the resizing event not to fire in react-big-calendar. The best fix for now is probably just to downgrade react and react-dom in your package.json (I went to "16.13.1" it is working fine)

Comment: The issue is still not resolved and resize still does not work on v17. Is there a way we can fix this ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

I think with the latest version of `react-big-calendar v0.38.1` everything works fine without any issues even with `react and react-dom v17.0.2`. I just had a bit of a hard time figuring out that I need to include the dragAndDrop styles `import 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css';` as well otherwise the handlebars for resize are not shown at all.